# Unable to install Requests module in python2.7 (Kali linux) as it keeps appearing in python3 library

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-requests

I am using kali linux and is trying to import a module called requests to run an exploit. (https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/47138) if you want to know more about the exploit.
when i try to run the following command

`sudo pip install requests`

i kept getting this result

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.23.0)
```

this cant work at all as i requires the Requests module to be in python2.

How can i get it installed?

Comment: Not clear why you need Python2 or are using sudo with pip

Comment: Why not just upgrade the code to run with Python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install <package> -t <directory>
```

-t specifies the target directory where you want your package to be installed

So in your case you can do **pip install requests  -t  "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages"** (This is where my site-packages folder is.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use this command, it will ensure you are installing the module for python2:

```
python2 -m pip install --user --upgrade requests
```

Comment: i got a /usr/bin/python2: No module named pip
so i proceeded with sudo apt-get install python-pip
but i got 

Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python3-pip

E: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following command:

```
sudo pip2.7 install requests
```

(Assuming that you have Python 2.7. If you have a different version, swap out the version number)

Comment: Unless pip2.7 is different than pip, you should use `pip2.7 install requests --user` without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Python 2 installation. It could be at

cd \Python27\scripts **or** cd /lib/python2.7 (in my case)

run pip install requests

If successful, You get:
Installing collected packages: idna, certifi, chardet, urllib3, requests
Successfully installed certifi-2021.10.8 chardet-4.0.0 idna-2.10 requests-**2.27**.1 **urllib3**-1.26.18